# Teaching Machshava and Hashkafa to Non-Jews

Tags: halacha, hashkafah-philosophy, gentiles

I know there is a prohibition against teaching Oral Torah to Non-Jews, but what about Machshava and Hashkafa? Sometime Non-Jews ask questions and the answer relates to either Hashkafa/Machshava. Is it permissible to discuss this with them?

Comment: Presumably no because it is part of the oral law. Presumably yes because Jews are meant to share their outlook with the world.

Comment: for an answer to a related question see http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/68529/11501