# Gentile Writing Devar Torah

Tags: halacha, gentiles, torah-study

I am a gentile and I wish to write a commentary on Bereshis 1 that digs somewhat deeply into the Torah. May I do this?

Comment: You might find this relevant: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/68529/11501