# Are goyim allowed to learn chassidus?

Tags: halacha-theory, noachide-laws

It's known (Sanhedrin, don't have exact pages) that a goy is in general only supposed to learn the parts of Torah that have to do with the 7 mitzvos

The question is, is chassidus considered all an elaborate on the unity of Hashem, and thus an explanation of not worshipping idols and/or not "blessing" Hashem's name, and therefore it would be permitted for a goy to learn all of chassidus without any problem, or does it depend on what parts of chassidus? And if so, what?

For example, many would consider Likutei Sichos as "chassidus", but many parts of it involve understanding different opinions in the gemara etc. which is seemingly only a part of Torah for yidden, but still it almost always brings the deeper spiritual meanings etc. so perhaps it's also an extension of the unity of Hashem?

Basically, can goyim learn all parts of all kinds of chassidus without any problem whatsoever, or would they be allowed to only learn some parts of chassidus? And if so, what parts should they learn, and how should it be measured?

Comment: The original question was if Jews were allowed to...

Comment: @user6591 and this question is w aboutgoyeem

Comment: It might be more productive to ask what part/aspect of Torah are non-Jews forbidden to learn and why.

Comment: Presumably they only can learn that which directly helps them fulfill their commandments.

Comment: @N.T. That’s how most people understand it, but there’s much more to it if you start looking. I’m not particularly interested in addressing this based on the wording of this question.

Comment: relevant sources: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/68529/11501

Comment: @yaacov t says in Likutei Torah that nistar is basically mikruh

Comment: John, you would do much better to give specific citations and links in regard to your comments. Your actual question is not about chassidut of any type. It is about what the deeper understanding is of the prohibition mentioned in Mishneh Torah, Laws of Kings & their Wars, chapter 10:9.

Comment: @mbloch As usual, excellent reference.